# (scheme) Verify if an element in one list is in the second list with do cicle

Tags: scheme, racket

How do we verify in scheme with the do cicle, if an element of the first list is in the second?

Comment: You really need to provide some more details to get an answer.

Comment: This is homework, yes? Retag if not.

Comment: Most loops aren't circles. Things like the `do` loop are not circles, so I was very confused when I saw this question, and I couldn't understand what you meant until I saw the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The do loop in racket has an interesting structure:

```
(do ([id init-expr step-expr-maybe] ...)
    (stop?-expr finish-expr ...)
  expr ...)
```

The documentation for r5rs provides an example:

```
(let ((x '(1 3 5 7 9)))
  (do ((x x (cdr x))
       (sum 0 (+ sum (car x))))
      ((null? x) sum)))
```

That statement returns 25, the sum of the elements of the loop. The `x` in the do loop is initialized to the `x` in the let, and then iteratively set to the `cdr` of itself each time through the loop. `sum` is initialized to 0, and accumulates the value of the `car` of `x` each time through. The stopping condition is when the iteration variable is empty, and the return value is the sum.

Ok, aside from the racket preference of square brackets, this looks good. There's a do loop and a list. The loop does something over that list. We can use that to write a function that finds a specific atom in a list (using the racket brackets):

```
(define (find5 lst)
  (do ([x lst (rest x)]
       [found #f (or found (eq? 5 (first x)))])
    ((null? x) found)))
```

Instead of initializing and adding the value `sum`, I `or` into `found`. Also, I prefer `first` and `rest` over `car` and `cdr` and define them myself when they don't exist. The way this function works should follow from the explanation of the example.

```
(find5 '(1 2 3 4 6))
```

Gives #f, as expected. Similarly:

```
(find5 '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

Gives #t.

Are you able to generalize finding a specific element in a list with a do loop into your specific question?

Comment: yes, thank you for the answer. I was not familiarize with cicle in scheme, I tried to understand, but i only understand simple functions, but yesterday i needed to make a function that see if an  elemment is in the second list. And I couldt make it, because in couldnt understand the stoppage condition.